# Formatting Sandbox – Please test stuff here

Tags: discussion, formatting

What the title says.

Use this for testing stuff and gosh I can't believe we didn't have this till now.

Comment: Related http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/237

Comment: `[chat] [ell.se] [meta.se] [su] [tour] [ask] [answer] [FAQ] *Slanted* **text** is ***really slanted*** [help] [tag:grammar] [meta-tag:discussion] [edit] and that's about all the useful tricks you can do with comments, I think.` -> [chat] [ell.se] [meta.se] [su] [tour] [ask] [answer] [FAQ] *Slanted* **text** is ***really slanted*** [help] [tag:grammar] [meta-tag:discussion] [edit] and that's about all the useful tricks you can do with comments, I think.

Comment: `[meta.ell.se]` [meta.ell.se]

Comment: @Colleen also, on the main site, `[meta]` does the trick.

Comment: Actually I was testing to see if `[meta.english.se]` [meta.english.se] would work on [ell.se] in a comment.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Recursive [edit] to edit

Answer (score 11):

> ## Trick no. 1: Headers

## The biggest, baddest header

### Header *less important*

#### **Can this header be bold enough?** Nope.

```
#The biggest, baddest header

## Header *less important*

### **Can this header be bold enough?** Nope.
```

---

> ## Trick no. 2: Lines

Adding `---` or `___` will add a line that visually looks like this:

---

If you want the line bold, add a `#` before `___`. Tho' to get the impression of a line you need to do some copy-paste or *keyboard press determination*.

## ----------------------------------

## __________________________________

```
#----------------------------------

#__________________________________
```

> ## Trick no. 3: Misc

- You can

  1. nest
  2. numbered or unenumerated

     - lists.
  3. Yay!

Studies™ prove that a shocking number of users don't know that two spaces at the end of a line can break the line, like a `<br/>`.

> I am a cool person.
>   You have no idea how cool you are too.
>
> I am a cool person. 
>   You have no idea how cool you are too.
>
> I am a cool person.
>   You have no idea how cool you are too.

```
> I am a cool person.  
You have no idea how cool you are too.

> I am a cool person. <br/>
You have no idea how cool you are too.

> I am a cool person.
You have no idea how cool you are too.
```

(There are two spaces after "person" in the first line of the first showcase)

## Secrets

> Use `>!` for spoilers and if you ever want a redacted effect without actually redacting anything.

The `>!` formatting works for images also

> [image: My cat Loki]

`<span style="text-decoration: blink;">Text to blink here</span>` Span Doesn't work
<del>Peter's exuberant use of bolding in his answers make me grateful the blink tag doesn't work</del> <sup>That's not nice</sup> <sub>It's not that mean though</sub>

`<kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>`
<kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>

```
1. Markup ordered list item
43. It's OK if the numbers are out of order
8. Another list item
```

1. Markup ordered list item
2. It's OK if the numbers are out of order
3. Another list item

Comment: Does `<kbd>` work in comments? <kbd>tilde</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

## Working with Images

**Changing the displayed size by adding a suffix**

If you upload your image to Imgur, adding a character to the end of the image name before the extension will change the displayed size in your post. The square suffixes (s and b) do not keep the proportions of the images but the rest of them do. There may be some problems with resizing PNGs that have a transparent background.

<kbd>s</kbd> - small square 90x90
<kbd>b</kbd> - big square 160x160
<kbd>t</kbd> - small thumbnail 160x160
<kbd>m</kbd> - medium thumbnail 320x320
<kbd>l</kbd> - large thumbnail 640x640
<kbd>h</kbd> - huge thumbnail 1024x1024

Original upload

```
 [![My cat Loki][1]][1] 
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg
```

[image: My cat Loki]

Displayed as a medium thumbnail (m) that opens the original size when you click:

```
[![My cat Loki][2]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyGm.jpg
```

[image: My cat Loki]

Also, you don't have to use numbers to mark the images; you can use any string. You can also add a description that will appear as a tool tip for any link by putting it in quotes after the URL. For example:

```
[![My cat Loki][Thumbnail]][Full]
[Full]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg "click for full-size image"
[Thumbnail]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyGs.jpg
```

[image: My cat Loki]

You don't have to link to an image either - any link will work:

```
[Thumbnail]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyGs.jpg
[InfoLink]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2133/
[![My cat Loki][Thumbnail]][InfoLink]
```

[image: My cat Loki]

When the resizing doesn't work, or if you want to choose a size other than the standard sizes, you can use HTML and still link to the full sized image:

```
[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg" width="200" alt="My cat Loki"/>][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg
```

[image: My cat Loki]

Be sure to put your width and height tags **before** the "alt" tag or your image may not be displayed:

```
[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg" alt="My cat Loki" width="200"/>][1]
```

Comment: Great tip for resizing huge images, will save users lots of time. Thanks.  Pity about SE not allowing users to centre images.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the <center> tag and the align attribute for <img> aren't supported in HTML 5, so centering things that the page doesn't always center is a lot more complicated. I'll see if I can figure out any way to do it.

Comment: @Mari you can use <pre>, or in Mathjax-supported sites, \hspace. That said, http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?s=1|0.4349

Comment: @M.A.R. Yes, we have a link to that in a different answer, but I think folks were overlooking it. Also, our community doesn't all have community wiki editing privileges on the other site, which makes it difficult to test stuff. <pre> won't center it, it will just indent it by a fixed amount and because the mobile site does center, it's unclear to me whether <pre> would undo that entirely.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could use something other than numbers!  Thanks, that'll definitely make things less confusing for me in the future :-)

Answer (score 8):

Horizontal spacing
　Horizontal spacing
　　Horizontal spacing
　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　　Horizontal spacing
　　　Horizontal spacing
　　Horizontal spacing
　Horizontal spacing
Horizontal spacing

**Hint:**
You can copy and paste the space between these two arrows to move your text: →　←

Comment: Alternately, the code for extra spaces that don't get automatically condensed is **&#160;** This will work in questions and answers, but not in comments.

Answer (score 6):

Did you know you can use [HTML character escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)?

You can use the name from the first column of that table :

`&mdash; &ndash; &para; &hellip; &uarr; &darr; &larr; &rarr; &copy; &pound; &Otilde; &check;`
— – ¶ … ↑ ↓ ← → © £ Õ ✓

Or the numbers by adding #:

`&larr;  &#8592; &#120;`
←  ←  x

SoundCloud links don't work here, but they do [on other meta sites](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176).

https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins

Comment: Does &larr; work in comments ?

Answer (score 6):

## Would you like

### to make your text

**look smaller**

<sub>**and smaller**</sub>

<sub><sup>**and smaller**</sup></sub>

<sub><sup><sub>**and smaller**</sub></sup></sub>

<sub><sup><sub><sup>**and smaller**?</sup></sub></sup></sub>

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>**Eeek!**</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

```
# Would you like

## to make your text

**look smaller** 
  
<sub>**and smaller**</sub>   
       
<sub><sup>**and smaller**</sub></sup>     

<sub><sup><sub>**and smaller**</sub></sup></sub>    

<sub><sup><sub><sup>**and smaller?**</sub></sup></sub></sup>

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>**Eeek!**</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>
```

Comment: I wish it worked in comments. SE hates fun. :(

Comment: It's best to avoid making text very small, most of the time.  People have trouble reading it.

Comment: @snailplane it's only for fun that I posted it as small as it could go. Certainly, one could do steps 3 and 4, without affecting legibility. It's very useful tip for shortening the amount of space long book titles take up.

Answer (score 5):

## Working with block quotes

#### Separating quote blocks

`> This is my first quote.`

`<!-- I want a blank line between them so I am using an HTML comment. This could be empty. -->`

`> This is my second quote`

> This is my first quote.

> This is my second quote.

#### Nesting quotes

`> Sometimes I want to quote something`
`>> Inside a block quote.`

`> And then keep writing the rest of the quote. I need to put a blank line to get out of the nested quote.`

> Sometimes I want to quote something
>
> > Inside a block quote.
>
> And then keep writing the rest of the quote. I need to put a blank line to get out of the nested quote.

Answer (score 5):

#　　　　　　　　　　　　　¯\*(ツ)*/¯

#　　　　　　　Does this thing appear at the centre?

> [image: It appears to be almost centered on my PC]

Comment: It looks completely weird on the android app, I just checked.

Comment: Should I delete this after test run? Or keep it here for just fun?

Comment: Nah, why delete? This post would be useful for future tests

Comment: @M.A.R. Alright. It will stay then. :)

Comment: Does this work on comments? (EDIT: It doesn't.)

Comment: <del>strikethrough text</del>

Comment: There's no way to get strikethrough text in comment except ugly Unicode. --- works in chat, and `<s>` works on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

I can't delete it right away. So someone like @IͶΔ could read something embarrassing I write here and use it to blackmail me.

Comment: Just write whatever you like here. I promise I wouldn't read it more than 5 times a day.

Comment: O.O 11 more to go. Oh. That was 11.

Answer (score 4):

Testing the Tool tip,

- is working for a [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/80439/28470)?
- is working for the image?

[image: New logo]

Answer (score 4):

Abusing the `<kbd>` tag to add outlines around images:

<kbd>[image: screen shot of an example post]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: screen shot of an example post]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: screen shot of an example post]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: screen shot of an example post]</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

### Tables

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

| Left | Center | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 124689 |
| Second | row | 975257 |

```
| Left  | Center | Right |  
|:------- |:-------:| ----:|
| First    | row | 124689 |
| Second   | row | 975257 |
```

There is [an answer for the main Table Support "new feature" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357008/) that shows how to use HTML to incorporate different types of formatting into table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Testing "magic" links [engineering.se] [ell.se] [interpersonal.se]

Right now, "magic" links work in comments, but not posts.

Comment: Magic links do work in comments though: [interpersonal.se] `[interpersonal.se] ` works in the comments.