# How to make hyperlinks on English Language Learners Stack exchange

Tags: support

Explain how to make hyperlinks on English Language Learners Stack Exchange for me please?

Comment: Also, you can always add another answer to the [sandbox post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2923/) to experiment with formatting. Just ignore the pop-up about how many answers it already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posts, you can just paste the URLs, but sometimes it is nice to have the link be the description instead of the URL.

Bare URL: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link
Descriptive link with a tool tip: [the Merriam-Webster definition of link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link)

Mark-up for the text above:

```
Bare URL: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link  
Descriptive link with a tool tip: [the Merriam-Webster definition of link][definition]

[definition]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link "an 
identifier attached to an element (such as an index term) in a system in 
order to indicate or permit connection with other similarly identified 
elements; especially : one (such as a hyperlink) in a computer file"
```

Here is the snippet from the editing help - let me know if you have questions about the text. I learned something new from reading this - the link identifiers in the `[]` don't have to be numbers!

```
In most cases, a plain URL will be recognized as such and automatically linked:

Visit https://area51.stackexchange.com/ regularly!
Use angle brackets to force linking: Have you seen <https://superuser.com>?
```

Visit https://area51.stackexchange.com/ regularly!
Use angle brackets to force linking: Have you seen https://superuser.com?

```
To create fancier links, use Markdown:

Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)! And a reference-style link to [a panda][1].
References don't have to be [numbers][question].

 [1]: https://notfound.stackexchange.com/
 [question]: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481
```

Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)! And a reference-style link to [a panda](https://notfound.stackexchange.com/).
References don't have to be [numbers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481).

```
You can add tooltips to links:

Click [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com "this text appears when you mouse over")!
This works with [reference links][blog] as well.

 [blog]: https://stackoverflow.blog/ "click here for updates"
```

Click [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com)!
This works with [reference links](https://stackoverflow.blog/) as well.